# Why is my form validation not getting set in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

im trying to create a templated system with CI.  So far everything is working flawlessly and im testing out form validation but its not working at all.  As you can see from the code below there are both html5 required statements as well as the codeigniter rules.  Neither of which are working after I hit the submit button.  So i'm not sure whats going wrong.  Something stupid im sure.

```
public function show_form(){



    $form_data = '<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card-box">
                <h4 class="m-t-0 header-title"><b>Basic Form Wizard</b></h4>

                <form id="basic-form" action="#">
                    <div>
                        <h3>Account</h3>
                        <section>
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label " for="username">User name *</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="username" name="username" type="text">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label " for="password"> Password *</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required form-control">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group clearfix">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label " for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required form-control">
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </section>


                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </div>

                </form> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    $this->CI->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');

    if ( $this->CI->form_validation->run() == FALSE ):
        echo "<pre>Before Validation</pre>";
        echo validation_errors();
        echo "<pre>After Validation</pre>";
        echo $form_data;
    else:
        echo "We did it";
    endif;


}
```

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Comment: The validation part should be on controller explained here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-controller and here http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#the-form

Comment: the second link you pasted shows `validation_errors()` directly above the form in the view file as I have here.  I can't call it from the controller because its loaded dynamically

Comment: I found out that when i use this `echo form_open($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "/admin/users/list");` the `$_POST` object gets populated but this URL resolves to `mydomain.com/index.php/admin/users/list`.  I already have my .htaccess file removing the index.php file so im not sure why it still remains after the submit button has been clicked